# Using SDL with C - Why is the window not showing up?

Tags: c, rendering, sdl, game-loop

I wrote an application that is supposed to render a window in a tight game loop. However, while the program compiles and runs fine, it doesn't render onto the screen; it only shows up on the taskbar. I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
#include "constants.h"

int gameRunning = FALSE;
SDL_Window* window = NULL;
SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;

int initialize_window(void){
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error init SDL\n");
        return FALSE;
    };
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(
            NULL, 
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 
            800,
            600,
            SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS
    );
    if (!window){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
        return FALSE;
    }
    // -1 is the default for all drivers
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
    if (!renderer){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

void process_input(){
    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_PollEvent(&event);

    switch (event.type){
        case SDL_QUIT:
            gameRunning = FALSE;
            break;
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE){
                gameRunning = FALSE;
            }
            break;
    }
}

void update(){

}

void render(){

}

void setup(){

}

void destroy_window(){
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    gameRunning = initialize_window();

    setup();

    while (gameRunning){
        process_input();
        update();
        render();
    } 

    destroy_window();

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The code itself compiles fine, but I only get this in the taskbar:

[image]

I saw someone use the same code in Linux, and the the screen did render. I'm not using Cygwin, I'm using MinGW (not sure if the POSIX standard might be coming into play when comparing to Linux).

Basically, I'm just asking if my code is wrong? The window won't show up on the screen. Unfortunately this is one of the harder ones, because there's no error messages to show.

Comment: 1. `process_input` is written incorrectly, you must do `while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))` to process all available events. (It shouldn't do anything bad in this case, in general it won't work properly.) 2. Try actually drawing something. Maybe the window is transparent somehow? Also try removing `SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS`.